# Как ограничить количество прыжков в Unity 2D?

Tags: unity3d

Как ограничить количество прыжков до 2? Просто у меня получается много прыжков.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class hero : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator anim;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            jump();
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") == 0)
        {
            anim.SetInteger("Temp", 1);
        } 
        else
        {
            Flip();
            anim.SetInteger("Temp", 2);
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);

        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 5f, rb.velocity.y);
        rb.velocity = movement;
    }

    void jump()
    {
        
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * 5f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Заведите счетчик.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class hero : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator anim;
    Int jump_study=0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {

            if (jump_study<2){
               jump();
             }
            if (jump_study>0){
              jump_study--;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") == 0)
        {
            anim.SetInteger("Temp", 1);
        } 
        else
        {
            Flip();
            anim.SetInteger("Temp", 2);
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);

        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 5f, rb.velocity.y);
        rb.velocity = movement;
    }

    void jump()
    {

        rb.AddForce(transform.up * 5f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        jump_study++;

    }
}
```

Comment: All comiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!